# Can a subclass in Java override a set method and make the argument type more specific?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Say I have a class

```
abstract class A {
    ArrayList<?> l;

    public void setList(ArrayList<?> l) //set the list
}
```

Is it possible to do something like

```
class B extends A {
    public void setList(ArrayList<? extends Foo> l) //Set the list }
```

I basically would like to specify an abstract class with a parameterised field, where a class inheriting from the first class can specify the type of the field more specifically so that it must extend some other type.

Comment: No. Because it has to accept all the arguments that can be passed into a call to `new A().setList()`.

Comment: I guess it's a no to do exactly the same using your way

Comment: No. It will count as an overload, and hide the base class method. Not as an override.

Comment: @EJP It won't be overload and won't hide, it will cause a compile time error due to name clash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can a subclass in Java override a set method and make the argument type more specific?

No. When overriding a method the signatures (name and argument types) have to be the same after type erasure. See JLS 8.4.2 for more information.

> I basically would like to specify an abstract class with a parameterised field, where a class inheriting from the first class can specify the type of the field more specifically so that it must extend some other type.

```
abstract class A<T> {

    public abstract void setList(ArrayList<? extends T> l);
}

class B extends A<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void setList(ArrayList<? extends Integer> l) {

        //...
    };
}
```

Here the compiler will perform type erasure and the signatures will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make A generic:

```
abstract class A<T> {
  abstract void setList(List<? extends T> list);
}
```

And then make B something like:

```
class B extends A<Foo> {
  @Override void setList(List<? extends Foo> list) { ...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you generify the base class:

```
abstract class A<T> {
    ArrayList<T> l;

    public void setList(ArrayList<T> l) {//set the list
    }
}

class B<T extends Foo> extends A<T> {
    @Override
    public void setList(ArrayList<T> l) {//Set the list 
    }
}
```